# Notice : Undefined index: uid in

Tags: php

Проблема состоит в том,  что при авторизации на сайте ошибка исчезает (т.к. сессия uid). Если пользователь не авторизован то везде пишет Notice : Undefined index: uid in ...

как исправить эту ошибку?

```
class User {

public $con;

public function __construct() {
    $data = new Basic;
    $db = $data->getConnection();
    $this->con = $db;
}

public function IsAdmin() {
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT who FROM users WHERE uid = :uid");
    $stmt -> execute(array(':uid' => $_SESSION['uid']));
    $who = $stmt -> fetchColumn(0);
    if ($who == 2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function is_loggedin() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

в header:

```
<?php if ($user -> IsAdmin()) {?> Видят только администраторы <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Ну всё верно, если пользователь не авторизован, то откуда возьмётся $_SESSION['uid'].

Comment: как сделать чтобы не показывало эту ошибку ? Notice : Undefined index: uid in ...  User.php on line 15

Comment: проверяйте наличие $_SESSION['uid']

Comment: проверять isset ?

Comment: Можно и через isset

Comment: тогда выходит ошибка Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in

Comment: У вас неправильно сделан класс. добавьте поле `$uid` и присвойте ему значение `$_SESSION['uid'] ?? null` через конструктор. И в классе работайте только с этим полем

Comment: как правильно присвоить?